# A precise definition of weak solution for $\Delta u=0$.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Consider $U\subset \Bbb R^n$ an limited open and $u\in H^1(U)$. How i can define the weak soluton of the problem $$\Delta u=0.$$

$(1)$ $$\int_U \nabla u\nabla \phi=0,$$ for every $\phi\in C^{\infty}_c(U)$. But this implies that since $Du\in L^2(\Omega)$, there exists a sequence $\phi_n\in C_c^{\infty}(\Omega)$ such that $\nabla \phi_n\to \nabla u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$. Then, $$\int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\nabla \phi_n=0,$$ so $u$ is constant in every connected component of $\Omega$(?). is it possible that i have only costant solutions? Where is my error?

Comment: Is $u$ in $H^1$ or $H^1_0$?

Comment: $u$ is in $H^1$

Comment: But in the second case if i consider $\phi \subset C_c^{\infty}(U) \subset H^1(U)$ i obtain the first case or not?

Comment: I think that the definition depend by what $u=g$ on the boundary for $g\in H^1( U)$

Comment: In (1) I dont see why "since $u\in H^1_0$?

Comment: I edited.......

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the boundary conditions for your PDE problem in order to define a weak solution.

Your definition of weak solution is for the PDE problem $\Delta u = 0 \text{ on } U$, $u=0 \text{ on } \partial U$. The only solution to this PDE problem is the zero solution, which can be easily seen (for example) by the maximum principle.

Comment: In many books i found: Let $u$ be a weak solution to $\Delta u=0$. Page $78$ of the following link https://www.jyu.fi/science/en/maths/research/nonlinear-pde/pde2/lecturenote2017.pdf How i can to interpret?

Comment: Your error is that you assume you can find compactly supported functions $\phi_n$ converging to $u$. This would imply that $u$ has trace zero, i.e. belongs to the space $H^1_0$. This then implies that $u$ must be constant. I imagine that in your lecture notes, they aren't demanding that $u$ have trace zero at the boundary.

Comment: Your stated definition of weak solution works.

Comment: I think that this Is true from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648738/c-c-infty-u-dense-in-mathcal-lpu?rq=1 and therefore $\nabla u=0$

Comment: It is true that you can limit to any $u \in L^2(U)$ with functions $\phi_n \in C^{\infty}_c(U)$. However, it is not true that you can limit to any $\nabla u \in L^2(U)$ with functions $\nabla \phi_n \in C^\infty_c(U)$. In fact the only functions $u$ you can limit to in this way are the constant ones.

Comment: To prove this by contradiction, imagine we had such a convergence in $L^2$, with $U$ compact. Then integrating (or using the Poincaré inequality) shows that $\phi_n + c_n \rightarrow u$ in $H^1$, where $c_n \rightarrow c$ is a convergent sequence of constants. It then follows that $u$ must have constant trace $c$ at the boundary, and it follows that $u$ is constant since it is a solution of Laplace's equation.

Comment: (There are of course many harmonic functions on any compact domain $U$ that are not constant at the boundary.)